# No rule to make target needed by all-am

Tags: c++, makefile, manpage

I wrote a program in C++ and I'm using autoconf and automake. Also, I've made man page (`my_program.1`) in the same folder that has all source files, header files and so on.
In my `Makefile.am` I have this line

```
man1_MANS = my_program.1
```

When I say `./configure` it's all ok, but when I run `make` I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `my_program.1`, needed by `all-am`.  Stop.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: short answer: use cmake

Comment: It says "all-am", not "all-em". Perhaps you've been searching for the wrong phrase.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, it was typo in title. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Slava I wanted to use cmake but I must use automake :/

Comment: You have a `my_program.1` file in your sources? In what directory?

Comment: I don't have it in directory. It's in root folder of my project with al source and header files.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same message when running `make distcheck` and it was because my man page wasn't being included in my release distribution. Adding my man page to `EXTRA_DIST` fixed the issue.

In your case, that means the following:

```
EXTRA_DIST = my_program.1
man1_MANS = my_program.1
```